# JBoss. NullPointerException during deployment one of .ear

Tags: java, jboss

I've got NullPointerException during deployment on of .ear on JBoss. Have you got any idea how to fix this?

```
10:57:06,308 ERROR [fail] MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."XXX.ear".DEPENDENCIES: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."XXX.ear".DEPENDENCIES: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase DEPENDENCIES of deployment "XXX.ear"
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:166) [jboss-as-server-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1980) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1913) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.jboss.as.jaxrs.deployment.JaxrsSpringProcessor.deploy(JaxrsSpringProcessor.java:207)
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [jboss-as-server-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
... 5 more
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.jboss.as.jaxrs.deployment.JaxrsSpringProcessor.getResteasySpringVirtualFile(JaxrsSpringProcessor.java:137)
at org.jboss.as.jaxrs.deployment.JaxrsSpringProcessor.deploy(JaxrsSpringProcessor.java:203)
... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.jboss.as.jaxrs.deployment.JaxrsSpringProcessor.getResteasySpringVirtualFile(JaxrsSpringProcessor.java:106)
... 7 more

10:57:06,317 ERROR [server] JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "XXX.ear" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"XXX.ear\".DEPENDENCIES" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"XXX.ear\".DEPENDENCIES: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase DEPENDENCIES of deployment \"XXX.ear\"
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: java.lang.NullPointerException
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: java.lang.NullPointerException
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException"}}
```

Comment: Looks like a problem with Spring JAX-RS JARs.  Why Spring on JBOSS when you deploy as an executable JAR with Spring Boot?  Leave Java EE behind.

Comment: added  dependency javax.ws.rs-api (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api/2.0) to my pom file but it doesnt help.

Comment: Configuration is wrong, then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was an issue with JaxrsSpringProcessor, https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-4075. It is fixed on Wildfly 9. There's a reproducer application attachment on the link.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had space in my JBOSS_HOME file path. I removed it and now it deploys fine.

Answer (score 0):

My application is only Spring, I don't need to use resteasy and deploy to jboss eap 6.3. Exclude resteasy using the jboss-deployment-structure.xml file. For me solved.

```
    <jboss-deployment-structure>
        <deployment
            <exclude-subsystems>
                <subsystem name="jaxrs" />
            </exclude-subsystems>
        </deployment>
    </jboss-deployment-structure>
```